# Share cookies received from external source between Client and Server in NextJS

Tags: cookies, next.js

I got a backend, NestJS GraphQL, and I got authentiaction on it's side. On signIn query it returns 3 Set-Cookie headers: is_authenticated, access_token and refresh_token. I use useLazyQuery hook from apollo to make a signIn request. Everything works until I want to use these cookies server-side e.g. getServerSideProps. How to sync client and server cookies in NextJS? Do I have to set them manually?

When I console.log `getCookies(ctx)`, `ctx.req.cookies` it returns empty object. On client-side `getCookies()` also returns empty object, but these cookies are set, because I also have a `cart-id` which sets the cart user can use, and it works properly, after refresh, restart browser and even restart my PC. Where is the problem then?

Comment: Are you using any packages like nextAuth? Any code? Usually it's just forwarding the cookies using the `res.setHeader('Set-Cookie')`

Comment: I don't use any package, But I found out I should use NextJS as something like proxy for auth to set headers both server and client side

Comment: Can you share your solution? @DawidSzemboroski

Comment: @AdelBenyahia I ended up with creating an "auth proxy" where every auth request was catched by nextjs server and it was responsible for setting cookies and managing auth, something next-auth, but more controlled by me, I don't like using next-auth